# (Fluent) NHibernate, Asynchrony, and Looping Issues

Tags: c#, asynchronous, nhibernate, .net-4.8, mediatr

I'm having issues with the following:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < domainEvents.Count; i++) {
            _logger.Information("Publishing Event {@DomainEvent}", domainEvents[i]);
            _mediator.Publish(domainEvents[i], CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

Originally, it was a foreach-loop that I converted to a for-loop.  Normally, there's only one event that gets fired, so there's no issue.  When there's more than one event, I started getting errors like "This connection cannot handle MultipleActiveResultSets."  Adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` onto the connection string causes the first event to fire properly, but then the second event errs out with "Invalid Operation.  The connection is closed."

The event handlers execute code like the following:

```
        var approver = await _services.UserRepository.GetAsync(emailConfiguration.Notification.ApproverId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        emailConfiguration.Notification.ApproverName = approver.GetName();

        var messageBody = _messageBodyHelper.GetMessageText(emailConfiguration);
        var subjectText = _subjectHelper.GetSubjectText(emailConfiguration);

        var emailMessage = new EmailMessage()
            .SetFromAddress(_services.ApplicationConfiguration.WebmasterEmailAddress.EmailAddress)
            .SetMessageBody(messageBody)
            .SetSubject(subjectText);

        _services.EmailValidator.ValidateEmailMessage(emailMessage);
        await _services.Processor.Process(emailConfiguration.UserEmails, emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I updated the loop code above to the following:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < domainEvents.Count; i++) {
        _logger.Information("Publishing Event {@DomainEvent}", domainEvents[i]);
        await _mediator.Publish(domainEvents[i], CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

This did not fix it.

I also did the following:

```
    var domainEventTasks = new List<Task>();

    for (var i = 0; i < domainEvents.Count; i++) {
        _logger.Information("Publishing Event {@DomainEvent}", domainEvents[i]);
        domainEventTasks.Add(_mediator.Publish(domainEvents[i], CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(domainEventTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This also failed with the same errors.

The only way I successfully got everything to work was to use the following:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < domainEvents.Count; i++) {
            _logger.Information("Publishing Event {@DomainEvent}", domainEvents[i]);
            _mediator.Publish(domainEvents[i], CancellationToken.None).Wait();
        }
```

I know that what I'm doing here is effectively executing the asynchronous code synchronously because I'm blocking the loop from going forward until the call finishes.  I understand the above is also not a best practice, but it is what I need to use for now to get the code to successfully work.

What I believe is happening is that I have two event handlers executing asynchronously at the same time and using the same repositories. I do not, however, know how to resolve the issues at hand other than what I have done.

I hope someone might provide me with some ideas on the cause and/or possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple threads are activated using the same dabatabase connection wich can result that 1 thread closes the connection while another tries to make a database call.

Each handler should have its own standalone database connection. One option is to create a database connection inside the handler it self.